# How to prevent Writeboard from showing two hyphens as an em dash?

Tags: basecamp

In [Writeboard](http://writeboard.com/), if you enter -- (two normal dashes/hyphens), it gets displayed as — (one [em-dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash)).

That's probably fine and cool in most cases, but gets annoying if you'd want to document e.g. Unix commands—like `wget —auth-no-challenge`—for copy-pasting them later. This breaks down with the "clever" em-dash conversion.

I found a clumsy workaround: write the two dashes like -<b></b>- or -</b>- in the page source. **Is there any better way to avoid Writeboard converting the dashes?** Using `<pre>` tags for verbatim formatting doesn't seem to help in this case.

Comment: _"As part of refocusing on Basecamp, we’ve decided to retire Writeboard.com. You’ll still be able to create Writeboards inside Basecamp Classic and Backpack, but you’ll no longer be able to start new stand-alone Writeboards here at Writeboard.com."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writeboard uses [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_(markup_language)) as it's markup language, with limited HTML support. In Textile, inline code blocks can be created like this:

```
@code@
```

or, using HTML:

```
<code>Code</code>
```

Both of which are equivalent when processed. It's analogous to Markdown's (used here for all StackExchange sites) `` `Code` `` style. The results of these is:

[image]

The actual code used to produce the above screenshot is:

```
Use the <code>--flag</code>, such as <code>wget --auth-no-challenge</code>

Textile should support @wget --auth-no-challenge@ or @--flag@
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  I couldn't get `@code@` working in Writeboard, but `<code>` works fine.

Comment: @Jonik That's odd, I managed to get `@code@` working. The second line in the screenshot was actually created with that markup

Comment: Can you give a more complete example of using `@code@`? Something that illustrates where the code block starts and ends.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. :-) (Stupid user error: I tried things like `@code@ --`, thinking maybe it behaves like Writeboard's `bq.`) Thanks again!